# For solving a Pell's equation How many iterations should I run before confirming no solution exists.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I am running this piece of code from  rosettacode

```
import math
def solvePell(n):
    x = int(math.sqrt(n))
    y, z, r = x, 1, x << 1
    e1, e2 = 1, 0
    f1, f2 = 0, 1
    while True:
        y = r * z - y
        z = (n - y * y) // z
        r = (x + y) // z

        e1, e2 = e2, e1 + e2 * r
        f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2 * r

        a, b = f2 * x + e2, f2
        if a * a - n * b * b == 1:
            return a, b
```

Source https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Python

however rosettacode doesn't handle cases when no solution exists.
How many iterations should I run before ensuring no solution exists.

Comment: You can know the existence of solutions by theory. For $x^2-ny^2=1$, it has infinitely many nontrivial integer solutions iff $n$ is nonsquare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add at the beginning of your function:

```
if math.sqrt(n)**2 == n:
    return -1,-1
```

Comment: In my opinion, returning `1, 0` is more correct.

Comment: @Antoine even though what you return is trivial as long as the caller knows to identify  but curious why `1,0` ? is it because that can't be a valid solution?

Comment: I would consider the solution $a = 1$ and $b = 0$ valid. Trivial, but valid.

Comment: I had wrongly used the word "trivial", Here it clashes with PELL's terminology. It should be "immaterial".

Comment: Mathematically speaking may be you are right but programatically speaking what you return should depend on what programmer's need is . Maybe he would have to print "No soultion" on the screen or maybe he would have to do other calculations based on this return value in his main program. So programatically speaking the easier you make it to recognise that it's a "no solution" scenario the better it is. That's why I feel returning `-1, -1` or `None, None` is more apt.